# data bind doesn't update value Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm encountering a weird issue, where I have a click event, updates a value, I see it updating in the console but the HTML doesn't change.

**TS**

```
toggleTooltip = false;

displayTooltipMessage(flag: boolean) {
    console.log(flag); // Value passed
    this.toggleTooltip = flag;
    console.log(this.toggleTooltip); // updated value
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <button (click)="displayTooltipMessage(true)">Press me</button>

 {{toggleTooltip}}
```

> I don't see any error in the console nor the server

- I close/open my browser, clear the cache, restart server, clear IDE, etc doesn't helped

**UPDATE:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
      <app-button></app-button> /* WORKING HERE */
      <div
        *ngFor="let obj of ListOfObj"
        class="lookup-cards"
      >
        <ng-container *ngFor="let col oftTableColumns">
      <app-button></app-button> /* NOT WORKING HERE */
        {{ obj[col.field] }}
      </ng-container>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you always pass ```true``` so this.toggleTooltip always becomes ```true``` , but at first time it should change from false to true.

Comment: correct. But nor even the first time changes @FatemeFazli

Comment: I just tried this code in a stackblitz and it's working for me:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhsqqd     It changes from false to true on the display.

Comment: Works for me in stackblitz, maybe there is something wrong with the rest of your setup.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfyk77

Comment: it's weird maybe the problem is from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm so confused. I know it's a very basic question. it's just weird that it doesn't work. I will do more research on my environment

Comment: If you initialize `toggleTooltip = true`, do you see it in the HTML output? If not, try removing the button (or anything else until you find the cause of the problem).

Comment: @ConnorsFan I have updated my question. I have tracked it down. Seem like an issue with the ng-container

Comment: @DeborahK I have updated my question. After trying to track down the issue

Comment: What is the `<ng-container>` tag doing inside of the other one? Also: where is `toggleTooltip` defined? In the `app-button` component or in the parent component?

Comment: Could you click the link for the stackblitz I posted and update it to demonstrate your issue? I don't quite see how the updated code matches with the originally posted code.

Comment: @DeborahK, updated code is our parent component and <app-button> is the actual component with "Press Me" button.

Comment: @ConnorsFan the `toggleTooltip` is inside of the `app-button` component

Comment: I just updated the stackblitz to add the code as described and it still works fine for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhsqqd

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an object instead a primitive one. I noticed angular's binding doesn't work very well with primitives.

TS

```
toggleTooltip:any = {value:false};

displayTooltipMessage(flag: boolean) {
    console.log(flag); // Value passes
    this.toggleTooltip.value = flag;
    console.log(this.toggleTooltip); // udpated value
}
```

HTML

```
<button (click)="displayTooltipMessage(true)">Press me</button>

 {{toggleTooltip.value}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to solve the problem, but try defining a type to your variable:

```
toggleTooltip: boolean = false
```

And make sure those lines of code are inside your exported component.

Answer (score 0):

I think where you are changing the variable within the code you will need to use NgZone.

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone){}

this.ngZone.run(() => {
     this.loadData();
 });
```

This is similar to [Triggering change detection manually in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular)